# Select features from the attributes table without opening it in QGIS

Tags: qgis, export, select-by-attribute, select-by-expression

I have an attribute table with a vast amount of data in QGIS. I need to export only some of the features. Is there any way to select features without opening the attributes table?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sure, here some options:

Use the processing toolbox and one of these tools:

- Select by Expression
- Select by Attribute
- Select by Location

Or directly extract them via processing tools:

- Extract by Expression
- Extract by Attribute
- Extract by Location

You can find all of them within "Vector Selection":

[image]

Or do it by a manual selection via the selection toolbar:

[image]